# Blackboard problem with polynomial

Tags: mathematics, game, reachability, blackboard

The blackboard contains the two numbers 0 and 120. Each minute you are allowed to write an additional number $ x $ on the blackboard if $ x$ has not been written before on the blackboard and if $ x $ is the integer root of some polynomial $ P(x) $ in one variable whose coefficients are numbers on the blackboard. The game ends when you can not write further numbers on the blackboard.

Which numbers will be written on the blackboard when the game ends?

Comment: May the new X be any integer or is it limited in some range?

Comment: Is this supposed to have some neat trick or do can I just simulate it? Am I only expected to record unique values (not 12 122s or something)?

Comment: @StillLearning The new x may be any integer, no limits.

Comment: @kaine you're only expected to record unique values.

Comment: May a number on the blackboard be used multiple times in the polynomial?

Comment: @StillLearning every jnumber on the blackboard may be used as often as you like.

Comment: No, not multiples of a number on the board. Every number can be used many times.

Comment: Looking forward to the answer. I see no end to this as I can just keep adding new numbers. I guess I better no mention them as it will spoil the fun. :)

Comment: You should exclude the zero polynomial.

Comment: To clarify: do you mean a polynomial of the form $c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots+c_nx^n$, where $c_0 \dots c_n$ are on the board, and $n > 0$, and $c_n \neq 0$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), any integer root of the polynomial
$$a_nx^n + \dots + a_1x + a_0$$
is a divisor of its constant term $a_0$, if $a_0 \neq 0$.

We will never let $a_0 = 0$, since that means we can divide the whole polynomial by $x$ (repeatedly, if necessary; yielding a root $0$ each time, which is initially already on the board) and get a polynomial (with the same non-zero roots) for which $a_0 \neq 0$.

Thus initially, $a_0 = 120$, our only choice. From this, suppose we get a new root $p$, a divisor of $a_0 = 120$. Then the next minute, we can choose from $\{p, 120\}$, both divisors of 120, etc. Clearly, the integer roots we generate by this process will *always* be divisors of 120, positive or negative.

We show how to achieve *all* divisors of 120:

- First, $120x+120$ gives us $x=-1$.
- Then, $(-1)x^{120}+(-1)x^{119}+\dots+(-1)x^1+120$ gives us $x=1$.
- Then, $x+120$ gives us $x=-120$.

We can get $2$, $3$ and $5$ using only the coefficients in $\{\pm 120, \pm 1\}$:

- $-x^7 + x^3 \pm 120$ gives us $x = \pm 2$.
- $-x^4 -x^3 -x^2 -x \pm 120$ gives us $x = \pm 3$.
- $-x^3 +x \pm 120$ gives us $x = \pm 5$.

Aravind found a nice trick -- now that we have $2$, $3$, and $5$ on the blackboard, the other roots follow by dividing from $120 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. (If we have $p$ and $q$ on the board, we can use $px-q$ to get $x=q/p$, so first take $q=120$ and then repeat the process with $q \to q/p$ for a prime $p$.)

We can conlude that the solution set is precisely the set of positive and negative divisors of 120.

Comment: Cool. Best answer. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Every integer can be written on the board.

First polynomial:
$$P(x) = 120x - 120$$

The root of this polynomial is 1.

Any integer:

$$P(x) = x - x$$

In this solution, it is important to note that constants are not coefficients. Also note that $-$ is an operator, not part of the coefficient. Had it been intended as the coefficient, I would have written $x + -x$ (or even more explicitly $1x + -1x$).

**Edit**: As an added shortcut (thanks to f''), you could simply use this polynomial from the initial board to retrieve any value for $x$:

$$P(x) = 0x$$

Comment: How did you let -120 be a coefficient?

Comment: Is it valid to use `-120` ? It is not on the board...

Comment: You guys both didn't read the final sentence in the answer.

Comment: Only polynomials in one variable https://www.imsc.res.in/~kapil/geometry/prereq1/node5.html

Comment: @Haobin: there is only one variable in the polynomials above. The $y$ that I have used is a construction for the reader, not the participants of the game.

Comment: So you mean x-c, I guess the OP included constants to be part of coefficients. Good catch.

Comment: $y$ vs $c$ is an arbitrary complaint. I chose $y$. In order to alleviate any of your concerns, I have changed it once again.

Comment: If you find a "tricky" answer to a clearly "non-tricky" problem like this, just let the author know in a comment. Obviously this is not the intended solution.

Comment: @Mauris: It isn't intended to be a tricky solution (apart from the amendment, obviously). In attempting this, I came across a method to retrieve $1$ from the system. Having it, I can construct any number. How am I supposed to know that this is not what was intended?

Comment: I think the first part using `-120` is not according to the book but I like the last... `P(x) = 0x` will indeed hold for all values of x. +1 for that one.

Comment: I think constants are coefficients (namely, coefficients of $x^0$)

Answer (score 3):

I started like this

$$\begin{align}
120x + 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &-1\\
- x^{120} - x^{119} - ... - x^2 - x^1 +120 = 0 &\rightarrow&x &= &1\\
x + 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x& = &-120\\
x^7 - x^3 + 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &-2\\
x - 2 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &2\\
\end{align}
$$

Now we have $-120, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 120$.

Having both $-1$ and $1$ means that I can always get the negated value of any new number.

But I can't crack this puzzle as I keep finding new numbers.

Wonder if I got it all wrong...

Edit:

Some more (thanks to Aravind for the first 3)...

$$
\begin{align}
x^2 + 2x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &10\\
2x - 10 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &5\\
10x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &12\\
x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &3\\
\end{align}
$$

And

$$
\begin{align}
2x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &60\\
3x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &40\\
5x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &24\\
5x^4 + 10x - 120 &\rightarrow& x &= &4\\
4x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &30\\
4x^2 + 4x -120 &\rightarrow& x &= &5\\
5x -120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &24\\
3x^2 + 2x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &6\\
6x - 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &20\\\\
-2x^2 - x + 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &-8\\\\
-8x + 120 = 0 &\rightarrow& x &= &15\\
\end{align}
$$

So far I have

$\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120\}$ (and all the negated numbers as well).

As far as I understand from other answers/comments this should be the complete list. I still wonder how that is proved.

Comment: You can only get divisors of 120. Can you get them all?

Comment: Hmm... I see... I'll give it a try... 3 should be next then...

Comment: You can get 10 because 10 times 12 is 120 and you have 1,2 already.

Comment: 2x-10=0 gives 5, 10x-120=0 gives 12.

Comment: @Aravind - I don't have 10 on the board yet

Comment: Once you get the prime factors, you get all of them by division.

Comment: x(x+2)=120 gives 10.

Comment: Actually since we have two of the three prime factors, that gives the third by division.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the OP's intended answer is:

Exactly the divisors of 120. This is true of the non-zero numbers on the board at any stage. If $P(x)=0$, then we can write it as $xg(x)+d=0$ and $d$ is a divisor of 120, this implies that so is $x$.

StillLearning's answer shows that all of them can be obtained.

Once $2,3,5$ are obtained, other divisors of 120 can be obtained by repeated division, eg: $2x-120=0$ to get $60$, then $2x-60-0$ to get $30$ etc.